# Syntax error: "(" unexpected in Jenkins Groovy scripted pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jq

I have the following code in a Jenkins Groovy scripted pipeline.

```
cfn_template = sh(script: "aws --region $aws_region cloudformation get-template --stack-name $asg_cfn_stack_name --query 'TemplateBody' --output json", returnStdout: true).trim()

echo "Debugging test line-2"

def min_size = sh(script: "echo '${cfn_template}' | jq -r '.Resources.devfoenergybkrblueasgASG12345678.Properties.MinSize'", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

The first `sh(script: "aws ... json").trim()` is working fine and storing CFN template in to the Groovy variable `cfn_template`. However, the 3rd line is giving a syntax error.

Here are the relevant console log lines:

```
13:18:46  [Pipeline] sh
13:18:46  + aws --region us-east-1 cloudformation get-template --stack-name dev-fo-energy-bkr-blue-asg --query TemplateBody --output json
13:18:49  [Pipeline] echo
13:18:49  Debugging test line-2
13:18:49  [Pipeline] sh
13:18:50  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/and_deployment_feature_AGM-448-2/cdk_build@tmp/durable-6410a3dd/script.sh: 700: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
13:18:50  [Pipeline] echo
13:18:50  Failure at CDK deployment. hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 2
```

Please note that, I am trying to get the `MinSize` property of the Autoscaling Group (ASG) from the CFN template for a reason instead of getting it from the ASG itself.

What is the mistake here and how can I fix this?

I also have a Groovy variable `asg_logical_id` that sores the value `devfoenergybkrblueasgASG12345678`. I'd like to use this variable in the command that is giving syntax error now, instead of this direct value. I'm not sure if I face any other issue with that after passing the current issue. So, if you could please include it in your solution that would be helpful as well.

**Update**:

A typo in the first command `(CFN)` that was added after bring the command here from the code base has been removed.

The following two work on a Linux terminal:

```
cfn_template=$(aws --region $aws_region cloudformation get-template --stack-name $asg_cfn_stack_name --query 'TemplateBody' --output json)

min_size=$(echo ${cfn_template} | jq -r '.Resources.devfoenergybkrblueasgASG12345678.Properties.MinSize')
```

Comment: I don't know Groovy, but in POSIX shell (`sh`), `echo '${cfn_template}'` wouldn't print a variable's content, but the literal string `${cfn_template}`. In `sh`, you'd use double quotes instead of single quotes to get the variable's content (but they probably need to be escaped, as the entire `sh` code seems to be a string). If pipe commands into one another (using `|`) is the issue here, you could also use `jq`'s `--argjson` [option](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq) to import JSON content, but the quoting issue remains here as well.

Comment: Does `cfn_template` contain single quotes?

Comment: I don't know groovy either, but in the first `sh()`, the command contains `(CFN)`, which is not valid shell syntax, and (in the dash shell) *will* cause the error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. However, the error message seems to indicate the problem was on line 700 of /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/and_deployment_feature_AGM-448-2/cdk_build@tmp/durable-6410a3dd/script.sh. Is this a temporary file (in which case why is it 700+ lines long), or permanent (in which case what is it and what's on line 700 of it)?

Comment: @pmf - Single quotes is an issue for POSIX shell variables but not an issue for Groovy variables the way I am using. I have several places in the pipeline before this command and they are working.

Comment: @cfrick - `cfn_template` contains single quotes in any place it has scripts like UserData. Otherwise, it's a JSON with double quoted key-value pairs.

Comment: Then the non-shell-quoted-single-quotes will mess things up - pipe the output of your aws line directly into jq. I'd suggest to just do the job with plain exec/JsonSlurper, but then again this is jenkins...

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Thank you for pointing that. I updated the question. The typo in the first command `(CFN)` that was added after bring the command here from the code base has been removed. I also added the `shell` versions of those two commands those work in a Linux terminal.

Comment: This is unfortunate that the question got a downvote making it not qualifying for a resolution. If this was for the typo in the first command, that was removed with further information. Thais is a legitimate problem that I need a solution.

Comment: In `sh(script: "echo '${cfn_template}' ...`, is the `${cfn_template}` part expanded by Groovy before it's passed to the shell? If so, single quotes in it will absolutely cause trouble with how the shell parses it. This is not a problem when it's a shell variable (expanded by the shell) because shell variables expand *after* quotes etc are parsed (although if the shell variable is not in double-quotes, it'll still be subject to weird word-splitting and wildcard expansion).

Comment: Is it possible in this shell to use `@Q` to ask for shell-side quoting? That is, try out `echo ${cfn_template@Q}` (with manual quotes removed, and `@Q` added) instead of `echo '${cfn_template}'`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the value of `cfn_template` contains `'` chars -- which are also used in an attempt to quote it.  So the effective call is basically something like this: `echo ''('' | ...`.

So your options are:

- quote `cfn_template` on the groovy side so it can be used when you bang strings together for the shell
- do not use `echo`

  - use a temp-file to store the content and pass it to `jq`
  - pipe the content

    - directly send the output from `aws` into `jq` (e.g. `aws ... | jq ...`)
    - write the content on the groovy side into the stdin for the `jq` call